# Unable to expose a component library in react with webpack and babel

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, webpack, babeljs

I'm creating a small component library for react. Something that can be required like `var Components = require('components')`. This will have individual components, much like `react-bootstrap` does. I'm trying to use webpack with babel to compile this into an `index.js` file. The compilation went well. I published this to my local npm registry and installed it in one of my other projects. When I require it - `require('components')` - the require returns an empty object. Below is my folder structure

```
root
 |- components
 |   |- ImageEditor.js
 |
 |- lib
 |   |- index.compiled.js (file compiled by webpack)
 |
 |- index.js (requires ./components/ImageEditor.js, entry point for webpack)
 |- webpack.config.js
```

**ImageEditor.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Canvas from './utils/canvas';
import '../stylesheets/imageeditor.scss';

class ImageManipulation extends React.Component {
    static propTypes = {};
    state = {
        height: 200,
        width: 200,
        scale: 1.25
    };

    static defaultProps = {
        color: [213, 214, 217, 0.6],
        image: ""
    };

    ...

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="_react-image-manipulation">
                <div className="_cover-box">
                    { this.loadComponent() }
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default ImageManipulation;
```

**index.js**

```
import ImageEditor from './components/ImageEditor';

export default {
    ImageEditor
};
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
var path = require('path');
var NODE_ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
var WebpackNotifierPlugin = require('webpack-notifier');
var UglifyJSPlugin = require("webpack/lib/optimize/UglifyJsPlugin");
var CleanWebpackPlugin = require("clean-webpack-plugin");

var commonPlugins = [
    new WebpackNotifierPlugin({
        title: 'Contour Components'
    })
];

function getPlugins() {
    if (NODE_ENV == 'prod') {
        commonPlugins.push(new CleanWebpackPlugin(['lib/*']));
        commonPlugins.push(new UglifyJSPlugin({
            compress: {
                warnings: false
            }
        }));
    }
    return commonPlugins;
}

module.exports = {
    devtool: 'sourcemap',
    entry: {
        index: './index.js'
    },
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
        filename: '[name].compiled.js'
    },
    plugins: getPlugins(),
    module: {
        loaders: [{
            test: /\.js$/,
            loader: 'babel',
            query: {
                cacheDirectory: true,
                presets: ['es2015', 'stage-0', 'react'],
                plugins: ['add-module-exports', "transform-class-properties"]
            },
            exclude: /node_modules/
        }, {
            test: /\.json$/,
            loader: 'json-loader'
        }, {
            test: /\.png$/,
            loader: "url-loader?limit=100000&mimetype=image/png"
        }, {
            test: /(\.scss|\.css)$/,
            include: /components/,
            loader: 'style!css!sass'
        }]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['', '.scss', '.js', '.json', '.png'],
        modulesDirectories: [
            'node_modules',
            'components'
        ]
    }
};
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Do you have a package.json? By installing in your local registry do you mean `npm link` or something like `cp my-module node_modules/`?

Comment: We have setup a local npm registry. I have published to that registry. In my other project, I have added this as a dependency. `npm install` fetches the published module from that registry and installs it. I don't think that it has anything to do with that. Because, I created another js file that requires the generated file `index.compiled.js` and renders the component into an `index.html`. Then I hosted this file in a local node server. Even that didn't work. It failed with the same error.

Comment: Does the package.json specify your main file explicitly? If you look in `node_modules/components` in your other project, are the files as you expect?

Comment: Yes the files are all as I expect. Also the main file is mentioned explicitly. But even without the publishing, it is not working locally in a simple node server

Answer (score 0):

You are exporting component in the object in the default export.
Babel 6 produces the following CommonJS module for you. [See REPL](http://babeljs.io/repl/#?evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-2&code=export%20default%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20ImageEditor%0A%7D%3B):

```
exports.default = {
    ImageEditor: ImageEditor
};
```

Then you can use this component like this:

```
var ImageEditor = require('my-lib').default.ImageEditor
```

Your component is hidden under the default key. If you don't want it, use named exports instead.

```
export {ImageEditor};
```

For this, Babel produces the following code

```
exports.ImageEditor = ImageEditor;
```

Look, no extra `default` key, and everything work as expected

Comment: I have added the `add-module-exports` plugin for babel-loader in webpack config file to override this behaviour. So that I do not have to call `default` explicitly.

Comment: Okay, let's show your generated code with export then. I guess the issue somewhere here.