# Importing cdn of a local react webpack library giving a number in window object

Tags: reactjs, webpack, ecmascript-6

I have two react projects where these two projects share some common components. I want to bundle those components as a library from project 1 with webpack and I don't want to publish them in any third party library tools, I want to use the project 1 cdn to get those components in project 2.
I followed this stackoverflow answer 
 [library of react components in webpack bundle export to use in on runtime rendering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39846223/library-of-react-components-in-webpack-bundle-export-to-use-in-on-runtime-render)
but I'm getting Extract.entity value in window object as 1 (a number) instead of function or a class. This is my webpack config.

```
  entry: {
    app: paths.appIndexJs
  },
  output: {
    path: paths.appBuild,
    filename: "static/js/[name].js",
    publicPath: publicPath,
    library: ["Extract", "entity"],
    libraryTarget: "umd",
    umdNamedDefine: true,
    globalObject: "this",
    devtoolModuleFilenameTemplate: info =>
      path.relative(paths.appSrc, info.absoluteResourcePath).replace(/\\/g, "/")
  }
```

The following is the output of window object in console

```
Extract:{
  entity: 1
}
```